# How to debug SignalR server event that fails to fire from client?

Tags: c#, signalr

When I copy the code from [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) *into my current project*, I have no problems using their `Send` method.

However, in my own code, my server `Send` method never fires.

**Server code:**

```
public class ModelingHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string message) // my breakpoint is never hit here
    {
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(message);
    }
}
```

**Client Code**

```
$(function () {
    var modelHub = $.connection.modelingHub;

    modelHub.client.broadcastMessage = function(response) {
        alert(response);
    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        alert(1);  // this fires
        $("body").on("click", function () {
            alert(2);  // this fires too
            modelHub.server.send("test"); // never fires
        });
    });
});
```

I don't want to go messing with the library code from SignalR, but I'm not sure how to debug this any further.

I can't call the method from the console either:
`>$.connection.modelingHub.server.send("test")`

Note that when I implement `OnConnected` and `OnDisconnected` events in my ModelingHub subclass, they work fine. I've taken them out to debug the `Send` failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue stems from your class, you do the following:

```
public class ModelingHub : Hub
{
     public void Send(string message)
     {
          var call = message;
     }
}
```

But you aren't actually doing anything with your message, you need your hub to actually broadcast the data.  You would need to add code similar or this below your variable `call`.

```
Clients.All.broadcastMessage(call);
```

If you don't sanitize your data, the method body could be:

```
public void Send(string message) => Clients.All.broadcastMessage(message);
```

Also, if I recall that tutorial has an interface called `Send` which expects two parameters, you may want to also check there to ensure you modified to accept your single parameter.

Comment: I assumed that the breakpoint would be hit in `Send`, even if I did nothing useful with the incoming arg. I just implemented your code to make sure (and edited question with this update) and it does not work.

Comment: @JacobIRR I can't reproduce, it is working for me.  Do you have a JavaScript error in your console?

Comment: I think this is happening because of some auth code in the background. Trying to dig through that to find out where its hanging up. no console error

Comment: @JacobIRR I can help, need more data.  But I just got back from meetings.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because it is the correct way to do what I want in the confines of the question. I have to dig into some of this IIS/rewrite rules stuff tomorrow since the Auth side of this application is causing things to behave funny with SignalR. Thanks for you your help!

Comment: @JacobIRR You should not change your question according the answer. The problem was this answer solves in not in your question anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you reference the correct version of SignalR. The tutorial references version 2.2.1 but the current version is 2.2.2 so that is a potential issue.

Check the browser console to see if you have any errors and make sure the version numbers of the references match up with what you have in your project.